# How do I encrypt a file created by my program so as to require a password

Tags: c++, encryption

For my ops system class project I had to create a key logger in c++. I made a simple key logger to store the users keys in a file. The key logger creates a file "record.txt" on the users computer. It saves the keys pressed and time stamps them. I want to go a bit above of what is required for the assignment and have the contents of that file encrypted. How would I go about encrypting the file so when you click to open the file it asks for a password, and if that password is correct it decrypts the file? 
I'm just unsure if I should be using another program or if I can actually hard code the encryption in my actual program.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how secure you want the encryption to be.
For an uber secure, you could use AES-256 bit encryption.
For a simple one, a password based XOR obfuscation will suffice

```
ex: plain text data Xor password = hashed data
hashed data Xor password = plain text data
```

C++:

```
xor(key, strlen(key), data, strlen(data));

void xor(const char *key, int key_len, char *xored, int result_len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < result_len; i++)
       xored[i] ^= key[ i % key_len ];
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will look into this. yeah I don't want it uber secure, just something to show more initiative since I am unfamiliar with encryption.

Comment: Just be aware that XOR encryption is basically worthless in any real-world security product.  There are libraries available that implement actual strong cryptography.